# How to run a Sikuli test as a standalone executable

Tags: python, sikuli, sikuli-script, sikuli-ide

I wrote some Sikuli code in my system using Sikuli IDE. How do I convert this `.sikuli` file and SikuliX setup to `*.exe` or `*.jar` and run in another system?

Just example code in Sikuli IDE:

```
type(Key.WIN)
type("Internet Explorer"+Key.ENTER)
click(Pattern("1517398787539.png").targetOffset(-41,1))
exit()
type('A', Key.CTRL)
type(Key.DELETE)
type("www.google.com"+Key.ENTER)
exit()
```

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: Sorry now you can find my Q...

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically you can do both but not directly from IDE. If you're more comfortable with Python, move your script to a standalone .py file and make it do what you want. Then you can use [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/) to convert it into a standalone executable script.

If you want jar then I think you have no other choice than rewriting your script in Java and then pack it into a jar with all the relevant dependencies.